# Assembling a two-dimensional array into a string in a specific order

Tags: php

help, I can’t think of an algorithm for assembling an array, there is such an array

```
$f_v = [
//    0 => [
//        1 => [
//            '1fv1',
//            '1fv2',
//        ]
//    ],
    2 => [
        1 => [
            '1fv1',
            '1fv2',
        ],
        2 => [
            '2fv1',
            '2fv2',
        ],
        3 => [
            '3fv1',
            '3fv2',
        ]
    ]
];
```

I need to collect them into a string in the order in which they go in these arrays

```
/*
 * 1fv1/2fv1/3fv1
 * 1fv1/2fv2/3fv1
 * 1fv1/2fv1/3fv2
 * and so on....
 * 1fv2/2fv2/3fv2 <- this should be the last combination
 */
```

Sorry if the question is stupid, but I've been sitting all day and can't figure out how to do it :(

Comment: Please explain the rules. I don't see how you go from the first line to the next.

Comment: first, the next first elements of the remaining arrays are added to the first element of the array, and then the next n elements of the remaining arrays are similar to the first, when they end in the first array, the next value is taken and the procedure is repeated (I hope I explained clearly)

Comment: The first line is `1fv1/2fv1/3fv1` - ok. Shouldn't the second line be `1fv2/2fv1/3fv1` and the third `1fv1/2fv2/3fv1`?

Comment: Damn it seems, yes, I was so worn out with this task that I even wrote an example with errors, but this is how it should be

Comment: what should happen with `$f_v[0]` ? why is it commented out? are there any other elements beside `$f_v[2]` that are relevant? I guess, that the sub-arrays of `$f_v[2]` all have the same length but there are n-sub-arrays?

Comment: It is assumed that the length may be at least 1 element (what is commented out) and there may be an unknown number of elements at the second nesting level, and at the third nesting level there is also an unknown number of elements but at least one

Comment: ok, and all arrays of the third nesting level have the same number of items?

Comment: No different, but you can stop at the quantity that has the least number of elements